# HttpClient - .net 4 or .net 4.5

Tags: .net, httpclient, consistency

I'm on the [Nuget HttpClient page](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) and the information there is seemingly contradictory. The very first paragraph is:

> This package provides a programming interface for modern HTTP
>   applications on .NET Framework 4, Silverlight 4 and 5, Windows Phone
>   7.5 and 8. This package includes HttpClient for sending requests over HTTP, as well as HttpRequestMessage and HttpResponseMessage for
>   processing HTTP messages.

But then, the third paragraph says,

> This package is not supported in Visual Studio 2010, and is only
>   required for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET for Windows
>   Store apps when consuming a library that uses this package. For known
>   issues, please see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=279987.

So, it's for "modern apps on [.Net 4] but targets [.Net 4.5]?

What gives?

Answer (score 2):

It's for apps that target .NET 4, because .NET 4.5 [has these features built-in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/08/15/asp-net-web-api-released-and-a-preview-of-what-s-next.aspx), so apps targeting 4.5 can just use the version that .NET ships with.

If targeting .NET 4.5, you need the package only *when consuming a library that uses this package* (obvious: if one of your dependencies depends on HttpClient, then you also depend on HttpClient).